# how to play a sound file using php script only

Tags: php

please tell me how to play a sound file(.wav) using php script. I need to get the values from DB and Depending upon the values i should play a sound file. thanks in advance.iam using linux operating system.

Comment: Where do you want the sound to play? Do you want it to play client-side, in the browser, or are you writing scripts to execute interactively server-side?

Comment: It wouldn't be possible to play an audio file using /pure/ PHP on neither the client nor server side anyway.

Answer (score 7):

PHP is only a processing language, it *cannot* play audio for the user, 
It *can* display HTML/Javascript code that will play the wav sound though.

Answer (score 7):

You need to embed player in HTML, if you have to do it dynamically using PHP, do something like this...

```php
$myAudioFile = "myAudiofile.wav";
echo '<EMBED SRC="'.$myAudioFile.'" HIDDEN="TRUE" AUTOSTART="TRUE"></EMBED>';
```

**Update:**
As per the new HTML5 standard we can use the built-in audio player

```php
$myAudioFile = "myAudiofile.wav";
echo '<audio autoplay="true" style="display:none;">
         <source src="'.$myAudioFile.'" type="audio/wav">
      </audio>';
```

Answer (score 3):

And on Ubuntu Linux install something like `play`

```
sudo apt install sox
```

(from https://askubuntu.com/a/920542/355766)

Then in php

```
exec('/usr/bin/play /path/to/audio.wav');
```

Answer (score 1):

On Windows we can use `powershell`:

```
exec('powershell -c (New-Object Media.SoundPlayer "C:\Windows\Media\notify.wav").PlaySync();');
```